# Doctrine Schema: Enum and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: doctrine

Doctrine documentation sucks. I can not find solution to my problem there.

I have code like this:

```
$logsTable = $schema->createTable('name');
$logsTable->addColumn('status', 'enum', ['notnull' => true, 'default' => 'first']);
$logsTable->addColumn('updated_at', 'datetime', ['notnull' => true]);
```

Qestions:

1. How can I add enum options (first, second) for status column ?
2. How can I define ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on updated_at column ?

Answer (score 0):

enum and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not supported with doctrine's schema.